# DataMapper join statements

Tags: ruby, join, datamapper

How does one generate a query with join statements using ruby DataMapper?

**ie.**

```
class Model1
    property id, Serial
    has n :Model2s, :parent_key => [ :id ], :child_key => [ :model1_id ]
end

class Model2
    property :id, Serial
    property :model1_id, Integer
    has n :Model3s, :parent_key => [ :id ], :child_key => [ :model2_id ]
end

class Model3
    property :id, Serial
    property :model2_id, Integer
end
```

now I want DataMapper to create a query like:

```
SELECT ... FROM model1 INNER JOIN model2 ON model1.id = model2.model1_id INNER JOIN model3 ON model2.id = model3.model2_id;
```

currently it lazy-loads all relations with single queries when accessing them which is very slow.

Comment: Do you want to generate that SQL query to gather data for, e.g., a report, or are you trying to fetch some instances and filter them based on their relationships?

Comment: Can you post the Ruby code that's triggering the unwanted behavior?

Comment: the code which triggers the behaviour is the iteration over the results and the nested relations from `Model1.all()` but it should not lazy-load the relations when accessing them but execute a single query when calling `Model1.all()`

Comment: I made some experiments here, but couldn't obtain the result you wanted. When using DM, I find that it's easy for you to navigate the database when performing mundane tasks, but if you want to make complex queries and you need performance... then you write your own queries. Not that there's anything wrong with that :)

Comment: @AdielMittmann, is it possible to write own queries and let datamapper store teh results in the defined model hierarchy? if yes, how?

Comment: You can use the dm-ar-finders gem, which lets you do things like this: `Model1.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Model1")`. But this will only apply to `Model1`.